# xmlhttpreqeust fails in post/get but not in regular form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, xmlhttprequest

When using xmlhttpreqeust the post/get request fails when the data exceeded 7k. (HTTP error 400)
When posting the same data using regular form submission ( etc . . .)  it works well.

Is there a limit to data size when using xmlhttprequest? or extra setting is needed?

Dev Inv: NetBeans 6.9.1.
Server: Tomcat 6.
Browser: IE8.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a GET, the data is limited by the length of the URL that the browser accept. Some versions of IE had a limit around 2 kB, so you should make sure that the data is well below that. A GET is simply not suited for sending a lot of data.

When doing a POST, the limit is much higher. The webserver has a default limit for the size of the request, which is typically something like 4 MB.

The same limits apply to a request using XMLHTTPRequest and posting a form. It's the method (POST/GET) that makes a difference for the limit.

Comment: @Guffa:If i'm using xmlhttpreqeust post is there away to change the limited size? so i will be able to send bigger data?

Comment: @user590586: You can configure the server to accept a larger request. However, that limit is almost certainly already substantially higher than 7 kB. If you are really sending a POST you should have no problem sending a lot more data than that.

Comment: @Guffa: By saying "configure the server to accept a larger request" you mean to set maxPostSize="0" inside the connector part of my server.xml ? If so , this is what i did , and it did not work.. any ideas?

Comment: @Guffa: another thing is that only when i;m using the xmlhttprequest i have a problem , if i use the regular form submit post it's works good..

Comment: @user590586: Is it possible that it's not the size that is the problem, but that the data contains some unusual characters?

Comment: @Guffa: the same content on both requests , and only when using  xmlhttprequset it is not sent to the server - and i get error 400 - badrequest.

Comment: @user590586: There is a possible difference when you are using a form; the browser will automatically pick an encoding that is capable of handling the data in the form fields, the XMLHTTPRequest object might not do that.

Comment: @Guffa: will try to see if this is really the problem.. thank's!